# NodeJS - Edit and proxy a multipart/form-data request

Tags: express, proxy, multipart, form-data, http-proxy-middleware

I have a microservice that proxies every request adding one more field to it. With normal requests it's very easy, just add the field in the *request.body* and properly set the headers but for multipart/form-data requests I'm in trouble since days because if I add a field in the *request.body*, it will disappear.

```js
const router = express()
const routes = require('~/routes')
const passport = require('passport')
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

router.use(passport.initialize())
require('./modules/passport-jwt')(passport)

router.use('/', routes)

router.use(
    '/account',
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    proxy({
        target: process.env.ACCOUNT_SERVICE,
        pathRewrite: { '/account': '/' },
        onProxyReq: restream
    })
)

const restream = async function (proxyReq, req, res, options) {
    if (req.user) {
        if (
            req.headers['content-type'] &&
            req.headers['content-type'].match(/^multipart\/form-data/)
        ) {
            req.body.reqUser = req.user
        } else {
            const requestBody = JSON.stringify({ ...req.body, reqUser: req.user })
            proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(requestBody))
            proxyReq.write(requestBody)
        }
    }
}
```

When the request arrives to the other microservice, the *request.body* is empty and after it will be written by [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) that will put multipart/form-data params into the *request.body*.

I really need a solution that let me append a field into a multipart/form-data request in the proxy *restream* function.

I tried everything to succeed in this but I'm stuck. I hope everything is clear from my side. Don't be afraid to ask for more details if you need them. I'm begging for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured out how to succeed.
My code now looks like this:

```js
const router = express()
const routes = require('~/routes')
const passport = require('passport')
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

router.use(passport.initialize())
require('./modules/passport-jwt')(passport)

router.use('/', routes)

router.use(
    '/account',
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    proxy({
        target: process.env.ACCOUNT_SERVICE,
        pathRewrite: { '/account': '/' },
        onProxyReq: restream
    })
)

const restream = async function (proxyReq, req, res, options) {
    if (req.user) {
        if (
            req.headers['content-type'] &&
            req.headers['content-type'].match(/^multipart\/form-data/)
        ) {
            // build a string in multipart/form-data format with the data you need
            const formdataUser =
                `--${request.headers['content-type'].replace(/^.*boundary=(.*)$/, '$1')}\r\n` +
                `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="reqUser"\r\n` +
                `\r\n` +
                `${JSON.stringify(request.user)}\r\n`

            // set the new content length
            proxyReq.setHeader(
                'Content-Length',
                parseInt(request.headers['content-length']) + Buffer.byteLength(formdataUser)
            )

            proxyReq.write(formdataUser)
        } else {
            const body = JSON.stringify({ ...req.body, reqUser: req.user })
            proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(body))
            proxyReq.write(body)
        }
    }
}
```

As I wrote in the code comments:

1. Build a string in multipart/form-data format that must look like this:

   ```
   ------WebKitFormBoundaryiBtoTWFkpAG6CgXO\r\n
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstname"\r\n
   \r\n\
   Andrea\r\n
   ```

   (In my code I stringified the data because was an object);
2. Set the header 'Content-Length' by adding the above string's byte length to the
   original request length;
3. Use *proxyReq.write* function to send the new data.

Comment: Thanks for this. You made my day.